# Spring webflow input validation

Tags: validation, jsf, spring-webflow

I have a page showing a table of elements to the user. To limit the result there is an filter input element above the table. The filter input has to be validated (it has to be a key of an organisation, checkable through database query).

If the input is valid, the page should be rerendered, showing the result of the database search. If it is invalid, the result table should be empty and a message should be displayed above the field.

Can anybody suggest some flow-definition-code how to achive that?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Validate your input :

`<h:inputText id="myInput" validator="#{myBean.myMethod}" validatorMessage="input not validated" render="myTable"/>
<h:message for="myInput"/>`

Set the rendered attribute of your table to not show if validation failed :

`<h:dataTable id="myTable" rendered="#{not facesContext.validationFailed}>
</h:dataTable>`